# 'EntityQueryable < ReportCompetency >' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working with a generic method that takes in a Logic Model and a Repo Model so that I have reuseable code that can update a display order.

The actual EF Call works perfectly, however I get the error

> The entity type 'EntityQueryable < ReportCompetency >' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.

The code I am working with is here

```
internal async Task<List<LogicModel>> UpdateDisplayOrderAsync<LogicModel, RepoModel>(List<GridItemAndSortOrderLogicModel> models) where RepoModel : TrainingBase
    {
        using (var context = GetDbContext())
        {
            var originals = context.Set<RepoModel>().Where(a => models.Select((b => b.Id)).Contains(a.Id));

            var loopy = from o in originals
                join m in models on o.Id equals m.Id
                select new { o, m };

            foreach (var loop in loopy)
            {

                loop.o.DisplayOrder = loop.m.DisplayOrder;

                context.Entry(loop.o).CurrentValues.SetValues(loop.o);
                context.Entry(loop.o).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation($"->> Updated comptency display order");
            var retVal = context.Entry(originals).Entity.Adapt<List<LogicModel>>();
            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

This call is made from this code block here

```
public async Task<List<ReportCompetencyLogicModel>> UpdateCompetencyDisplayOrderAsync(List<GridItemAndSortOrderLogicModel> models) => await base.UpdateDisplayOrderAsync<ReportCompetencyLogicModel, RepositoryModel.ReportCompetency>(models);
```

The line where I get the error is `var retVal = context.Entry(originals).Entity.Adapt<List<LogicModel>>();`

And would be grareful for any and all help on how to get passed this.

Comment: so the return should be a Task (`Task<List<LogicModel>>`)...can't tell if that is so but worth checking

Comment: is this ef-core or ef? is this .net or .net-core?  please streamline your tags

Comment: @JohnB yes, thats the intention

Comment: ef core and streamlined

Comment: excuse my ignorance, but I've not seen this `Adapt` function before -  is that an   extension method you authored?

Comment: originals is of type IQueryable<RepoModel>, so the .Entry() call on this is suspicious to say the least.

Comment: @JohnB its a part of mappster, its what does the mapping from one object to another

Comment: @DevilSuichiro what do you suggest in its place?

Comment: @SimonPrice this depends on what you want to accomplish with the code. I'd expect you'll want a .Entry() call on each of the values (like for loop.o) and add it to a list there, but the Entry(originals) call means EF will look for the DbSet<IQueryable<RepoModel>> to locate the entity, which most likely does not exist (since it cannot be mapped to a tuple)

Comment: @DevilSuichiro all entities exist and will exist at the point of update

Comment: @SimonPrice I'm quite aware of that. However, the Entry() call will retrieve the DbSet with elements of the type of the passed parameter to access the tracked entity. Your DbSet which tracks the objects is of Type DbSet<RepoModel>, not DbSet<IQueryable<RepoModel>>, so the entry call can't find a place to look for the entry and throws this exception (usually it can't find the DbSets because the passed entity is not part of the model instead of due to a programming error)

Comment: I think I am following now, squidy bit between seat and keyboard issue then...